# How to import a text file that both contains values and text in python?

Tags: python, import

I am aware that a lot of questions are already asked on this topic, but none of them worked for my specific case.

I want to import a text file in python, and want to be able to access each value seperatly in python. My text file looks like (it's seperated by tabs):
[example dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2VUI.png)

For example, the data '1086: CampNou' is written in one cell. I am mainly interested in getting access to the values presented here. Does anybody have a clue how to do this?

1086: CampNou   2084: Hospi 2090: Sants 2094: BCN-S 2096: BCN-N 2101: UNI   2105: B23   Total
1086: CampNou   0   15,6508 12,5812 30,3729 50,2963 0   56,0408 164,942
2084: Hospi 15,7804 0   19,3732 37,1791 54,1852 27,4028 59,9297 213,85
2090: Sants 12,8067 22,1304 0   30,6268 56,7759 29,9935 62,5204 214,854
2096: BCN-N 51,135  54,8545 57,3742 46,0102 0   45,6746 56,8001 311,849
2101: UNI   0   28,9589 31,4786 37,5029 31,6773 0   50,2681 179,886
2105: B23   51,1242 38,5838 57,3634 75,1552 56,7478 40,2728 0   319,247
Total   130,846 160,178 178,171 256,847 249,683 143,344 285,559 1404,63'

Comment: Please, add an exemple of the desired output, because you want '1086' from your exemple but what about all the number inside you file? Do you want CampNou as well?

Comment: As a desired output, for example i want to use the value 15,6508 for further calculations. But also the other numbers inside the file should be accessible.  The first row and first column are not important in the output

Answer (score 0):

```py
def read_file(filename):
    """Returns content of file"""
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    return content

content = read_file("the_file.txt") # or whatever your text file is called
items = content.split('    ')
```

Then your values will be in the list `items`: `['', '1086: CampNou', '2084: Hospi', '2090: Sants', ...]`

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can get this working in python 2? I can't use the latest version of python

Comment: looks like `encoding` isn't a parameter in python2. i've removed that from my answer, try that and it should work

Comment: This works indeed. Now i'm trying to access for example the value 15,6508, but how should this be done? When I type in print(items[0]) it returns the whole list, and not just one item

Comment: can you update your question with the actual file you are using?

Comment: I would like to, but i can't attach a file in my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to open and manipulate your data.

```py
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("mytext.txt")
```

This should read properly your file

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without using pandas?

Comment: Yes by using Ollie anwser. But when you get the list, you then need to write some function to get what you want.

Comment: Oke, how should this function looks like (i am quite new in Python so I have no clue)?